# Is each process considered a thread?

Tags: linux, process, c, multithreading

Is a Linux process considered a thread?

For example, if I write a simple c program that calls pthread_create to create a new thread in main(), does that mean that I now have 2 threads, one for main() and the newly created one? Or does only the spawned thread count as a thread but not the main() process?

I was wondering because by calling pthread_join to join the spawned thread to main() it seems like I'm *joining threads together*, thus implying that the main process is a thread.

Please also correct me if I use the wrong terminology. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man pthreads` in my computer

```
 In  addition  to  the **main (initial) thread**, and the threads that the 
 program creates using pthread_create(3), the implementation creates a 
 "manager" thread.  This thread handles thread creation and termination.
 (Problems can result if this thread  is  inad‐ vertently killed.)
```